# How to display servlet output using hyperlink tag of html

Tags: html, mysql, servlets, servlet-3.0, servletexception

I have to show result of servlet which is fetching data from mysql, on clicking one hyperlink in html. Please tell me how to do that. Thank you

Comment: on hyperlink give URL for servlet ?? , please be clear and more specific about what exactly do you want

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/). AJAX is a jQuery tool, which can send HTTP requests and change content dynamically.